# Zoom graphics processing 2.2.1

Tags: arduino, processing

help please, at Arduino Uno I receive a signal from the sensor and build a graph using processing 2.2.1, but you need to scale up without losing proportions. My attempts failed, the proportion was crumbling(I tried to multiply the values) Code:

```
    Serial myPort; 
int xPos = 1;  
int yPos = 100;
float yOld = 0;
float yNew = 0;
float inByte = 0;
int lastS = 0;
PFont f;
void setup () {
  size(1200, 500);
  println(Serial.list());
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  background(0xff);
}
void draw () {
  int s = second();
  PFont f = createFont("Arial",9,false);
  textFont(f,9);
  fill(0);
  if (s != lastS){
    stroke(0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc);
    line(xPos, yPos+10, xPos, yPos+30);
    text(s + " Sec.", xPos+5, yPos+30);
    lastS = s;
  }
}
void mousePressed(){
  save(lastS + "-heart.jpg");
}
void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (inString != null) {
    inString = trim(inString);
    if (inString.equals("!")) {
      stroke(0, 0, 0xff); // blue
      inByte = 1023; 
    } else {
      stroke(0xff, 0, 0); //Set stroke to red ( R, G, B)
      inByte = float(inString);
    }
    inByte = map(inByte, 0, 1023, 0, height);
    yNew = inByte;
    line(xPos-1, yPos-yOld, xPos, yPos-yNew);
    yOld = yNew;
    if (xPos >= width) {
      xPos = 1;
      yPos+=200;
      if (yPos > height-200){
        xPos = 1;
        yPos=100;
        background(0xff);
      }
    } else {
      xPos++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to scale graphics.

A simple method to try is to simply [`scale()`](https://processing.org/reference/scale_.html) the rendering (drawing coordinate system).

Bare in mind currently the buffer is only cleared when the `xPos` reaches the right hand side of the screen.

The value from Arduino is mapped to Processing here:

```
inByte = map(inByte, 0, 1023, 0, height);
    yNew = inByte;
```

you should try to map change `height` to a different value as you see fit.
This however will scale only the Y value. The x value is incremented here:

```
xPos++;
```

you might want to change this increment to a different value that works with the proportion you are trying maintain between x and y.